# Unity: Fatal Execution Engine Error when resolving a TimeSpan

Tags: .net, struct, unity-container, fatal-error

I am trying to resolve a [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) using [Unity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc468366.aspx). Executing the container Resolve call results in a [FatalExecutionEngineError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228990.aspx).

> FatalExecutionEngineError was detected
>   Message: The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x543c3dc8, on thread 0x1bb8. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.

Running the test in DEBUG causes the following file to be requested by the debugger.

> X:\Unity\Src\ObjectBuilder\Strategies\BuildPlan\DynamicMethod\DynamicMethodBuildPlan.cs

And it shows the following [ExecutionEngineException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.executionengineexception.aspx) on line 38.

> System.ExecutionEngineException was unhandled
>     Message="Exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' was thrown."
>     InnerException:

Test

```
[TestClass]
public class Example
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        container.Register<TimeSpan>(new ExternallyControlledLifetimeManager());
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        var expected = new TimeSpan();
        var actual = container.Resolve<TimeSpan>();
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know Unity has some default ctor selection rules, but I should at least be seeing a Unity exception.

Comment: This also occurs on other structs, like DateTime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you get the error, but I tried to replace the type configuration (in the configuration file you edited out) with the following it works.

```
<instances>
   <add name="MyTimeSpan" type="System.TimeSpan" value="1.02:03:04"  />
</instances>

var duration = container.Resolve<TimeSpan>("MyTimeSpan");
```

The above should return a timespan with a duration of 1 day, 2 hours, 3 minutes and 4 seconds.

(I tried this with Unity 4.1)

Comment: I performed `container.RegisterInstance<TimeSpan>(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));` and that resolves fine.

Answer (score 0):

## Fatal Execution Engine Error when resolving a TimeSpan

I posted [this issue on the Unity CodePlex site](http://unity.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=6491). It has been answered.

> In current bits **you get the proper "InvalidOperationException"**. TimeSpan has multiple constructors, and by default it picks the four-argument one, and then doesn't know what ints to supply. Structs don't actually have a zero-argument constructor, the clr "cheats" under the hood.

The solution is to tell Unity which constructor to use.

```
container.Register<TimeSpan>(new ExternallyControlledLifetimeManager(), 
    new InjectionConstructor(0L));
```

Comment: But I think the Register Instance solution is still the right one. It more accurately addresses the use of a TimeSpan in an IoC container.